# OpenCV Color Concentration Histogram

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ocr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am working on an ANPR system using OpenCV and have seen in a few articles a way of doing character segmentation. The idea is to make a graph showing the concentration on color across the image.

How do I do this?

[image]

This is the image that I have:

[image]

I need to detect the locations of the black areas as shown above to identify each of the characters.

I have tried adding the values up pixel by pixel but I am doing this on Android and the time this takes is unacceptable.

Comment: What is this image? How do you do what? Please try to add more details about what you actually have and what you want to do.

Comment: So you currently have the location of the black areas? Can you put a snippet of code for what you mean by "adding values pixel by pixel"?

Comment: If speed is your only issue then I'd suggest you scale your input image to a lower resolution by a factor of 2 or even 4. The input image you show is very high resolution for the task you want to perform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, its a month later, but I wrote you a little bit of code (in python) for this ;)

(Assuming you are just after the image density histogram)

```
import cv

im2 = cv.LoadImage('ph05l.jpg')
width, height = cv.GetSize(im2)
hist = []
column_width = 1   # this allows you to speed up the result,
                   # at the expense of horizontal resolution. (higher is faster)
for x in xrange(width / column_width):
    column = cv.GetSubRect(im2, (x * column_width, 0, column_width, height))
    hist.append(sum(cv.Sum(column)) / 3)
```

To speed things up, you need'nt alter your image files, just alter the bin width of the sampling (`column_width` in the script), obviously you lose some resolution if you do this (as you can see in the image below).

In the image, I show the results (graphing `hist`) with your file, using `column_width`'s of 1, 10 and 100. They ran for me at 0.11, 0.02 and 0.01 seconds respectively.

I wrote it in [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) too, but it runs around 5 to 10 times slower.

[image: character density histograms]

Answer (score -2):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  It does character segmentation the same way (using histograms).  It's fairly fast on a desktop, but I'm not sure how fast that would be on Android.